# Use docker image in .gitlab-ci.yml with build essentials and git

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Since I want to use `docker build` and `docker-compose` in gitlab CI, the image should be specified as `image: docker:latest`. However, when I run some scripts including git command, it turns out that git and other build-essentials are not included in this image. Even though I use `apt-get`, the command is still not found.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question is, how to add back the git and build-essentials in the yml ?

Comment: I changed to use docker:git as the image. It should be done right now. I will leave this question open to see if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *docker* image is based on [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org) and apparently uses a different package manager: [apk](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management).

So you can:

1. Stick to the *docker* image and use `apk` instead of `apt-get`.
2. Use *[gitlab/dind:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/dind/)* image instead as it's based on Ubuntu and contains `apt-get`.

In both cases it would be better not to run `apt-get` during the build process because it will slow it down and can possibly fail and make your whole build fail. Instead create your own Docker image based on one of the two images mentioned above and containing the extra tools you need (e.g. git) and use that own image in *.gitlab-ci.yml*.

### Sample dockerfile for your image

```
FROM gitlab/dind:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Is gitlab/dind going to be the image or the service ? Currently I am using the  docker/dind as service and docker:git as image.

Comment: You would have your own image based on *gitlab/dind* and that image of yours would be used as... uhm... image, not service, because it would contain all the extra tools (e.g. git) you need.